# Formalise: "It ain't over, till it's over"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, modal-logic

Formalise the statement: "It ain't over till it's over."

Writing this in formal English we have:

> "It is not over, until it is over."

Let:

> t: it is over

I am aware that this is a form of temporal logic as the propositions are qualified in terms of time. I.e. "until"

How would this be formalised? I thought $\neg$ t -> t could be one way as the end result is just t.

Also would this be a tautology, contradiction or contingent sentence?

Comment: In a logical view, the given sentence is a tautology. We could formulate it as follows : "If it is not over, it is not over".

Comment: Yes I thought as much. It's formalised form I guess would be $\neg $t -> t

Comment: A good non-temporal analogue of 'until' might be 'unless'. A proposition is not true, unless it is true.

Comment: @DavidH Yes I've tried to use  the conditional -> to get around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to read the sentence is to represent it as $\lnot t \implies \lnot t$, which is a tautology.  The intended reading makes use of an ambiguity in English.  Particularly for a sporting event "It is over" can mean the game is complete or it can mean that although the game is not complete one team is so far ahead the other has no chance to catch up.  The point of the statement is then to claim that no lead is safe until the game is truly complete.  To formalize this reading, you need two different symbols, one for each reading of "It is over".  So you can have $t$ be "the game is complete" and $s$ be "one team has no chance of winning" and say $\lnot t \implies \lnot s$

Comment: But then that's not a tautology. (Not t implies not s) has a false value in the third row... bit confused as I thought that a truth functional compound is a tautology if and only if it takes the truth value true in all lines of its truth table.

Comment: You are correct that it is not a tautology any more. The second way of reading is a different sentence.  It is the conflict between the two readings that makes it amusing.  It is certainly not a contradiction, either, so it must be a contingent sentence.  Translating English into formal logic has problems with this all the time because of the ambiguities in English.  Usually the hard part is deciding how to read the sentence.  The translation from unambiguous reading to logic symbols becomes rather mechanical.